# Reading data from a large file

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, hpc

I have a text file which is as follows.

```
0.031 0.031 0.031 1.4998 0.9976 0.5668 0.9659

0.062 0.031 0.031 0.9620 0.7479 0.3674 0.4806
```

and so on......

This is a 32^3 grid which means there will be 32768 lines. In each line, there are 7 columns. I need to read each column and store it in separate 1D arrays.

The Fortran code looks like

```
open(unit=1,file='32data.txt') ! that's the filename
do i= 1,32767
read(1,*) x(i),y(i),z(i),norm(i),xv(i),yv(i),zv(i)
end do
```

I want to know to parallelize this in MPI when a file bigger than this is given (say 512^3). I need to read in part of a data at a time and work(to minimise workload and also the master worker won't have enough local memory).

How do I start by sending pieces of data at a time?

Comment: I would first decompose the file into smaller ones. Like 512 files of 512^2 lines, for example. Using `sed` for example. But, this decomposition itself may not be parallelized.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, be sure to  take the [tour] and read [ask]. Avoid unnecessary noise like "help me" or "thanks in advance" and do not mark questions "- FORTRAN", the tags are for that.

Comment: Reading in a sliding window would help. But creating 512 files of those many lines would be too time consuming? Is there an easier way to perhaps read only part of the data by each processor and then globally combine it later?

Comment: @VladimirF Will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Text file is not a fit for parallel I/O. One file per rank, or binary data + MPI-IO is the recommended way. If not, having all tasks read the text file and skip some lines might be a lesser evil.

Comment: @Gilles Is there an example I could look at , for the latter?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the input/output part of parallel programs are not parallel.

norio suggests splitting the file ahead of time. This preprocessing will not be parallel. This is advantageous if your nodes have their own file system. If your cluster has a shared file system then all the nodes are going fight for file access at start up.

Option 2: As the master reads in the file, it distributes the data and forgets the data so it doesn’t run out of memory.

Option 3: Each node scans entire file ignoring lines not assigned to it.

Comment: Option 2 was precisely what I was looking for. But coming to that, the root process would read the entire file inorder to split data right? Will it have enough local memory to store it?

Comment: Let’s say you have 10 nodes. After 1/10 of the data is read in, the master node sends it to the appropriate node and forgets the data. (Deallocate or just use the same data structure for the next 1/10 of the data)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this sounds appealing. Is there any example I can refer to ?

Comment: IO can easily be parallel, using MPI-IO. And if the file system is shared and parallel, it is fine and faster.

Comment: I cwrtainly do not recommend reading the data by the master in chunks and sending it.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the insight. Is there any example that I can refer to? Or a source to read from ?

Comment: There are many, just search "MPI I/O". But it is a bit advanced topic. Use only if you know basic MPI.

Comment: Would it be plausible to use MPI_SCATTER? Can I consider this file to be a 2D array of 512^3 rows and 7 columns and send it off to other processes or is it not recommended?